# Angular 2's Http service not exposing map() and other RxJS functions

Tags: typescript, angular, rxjs

Does anybody know if there's been any breaking changes to the http between alpha 45 and alpha 48? I've been searching around and I didn't find anything. My problem is that the code below was working perfectly on Alpha 45. But now that I've upgraded to Alpha 48 I am getting a `_this.http.post(...).map is not a function` error message when I try to run the application. The strange thing is that IntelliSense shows that http.post is returning an observable. Which means that the map function should be available. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
public Authenticate(username: string, password: string): Observable<boolean> {

    this.ResetAuthenticationValues();

    return Observable.create((subscriber: EventEmitter<string>) => { 

        let body: string = 'grant_type=password&username=' + username + '&password=' + password;
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

        this.http.post('http://example.com', body, {headers: headers})
            .map(res => res.json())
            .subscribe(
                (data: DataResponse) => {
                    if (!data.error) {
                        this.accessToken = {access_token: data.access_token, token_type: data.token_type};
                        subscriber.next(this.isAuthenticated = true);                       
                    }
                    else
                        subscriber.error(this.isAuthenticated = false);
                },
                (err) => subscriber.error(err),
                () => subscriber.complete()
            );

        return () => { };
    });
}
```

Comment: Stick to alpha 47. They are [discussing](https://gitter.im/angular/angular?at=56636ef95057376520dbc193) what to do about how to ship angular2 along with RxJS.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**Another update** *(cough, sorry about that, forgot this option)*

If you want to avoid adding individually the operators you can import the full Rx by doing

```js
import {Observable, Subject, ReplaySubject, etc...} from 'rxjs/Rx';
```

You'll have all the operators :)

**Update alpha 50** (08/12/2015)

Shortly after alpha 49 was released, they released alpha 50. This version upgraded rxjs to alpha 14. So you'll good to go by doing

```js
npm install angular2@latest
npm install rxjs@5.0.0-alpha.14
```

**Update alpha 49** (08/12/2015)

As of now [alpha 49](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) was released and this didn't change, which means this will remain in time. The original answer is still valid with a few changes, paths changed for rjxs, so it should be as follows :

```js
System.config({
    paths: {
        'rxjs/add/observable/*' : 'node_modules/rxjs/add/observable/*.js',
        'rxjs/add/operator/*' : 'node_modules/rxjs/add/operator/*.js',
        'rxjs/*' : 'node_modules/rxjs/*.js'
    }
});

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

**Note**

This version requires exactly the `alpha 13` version, so if in your `package.json` you have already another version, you'll have to remove it, install angular2, and then install rjxs.

**Update**

The [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-alpha48-2015-12-05) was updated to show this breaking change. There's a [comment from @jeffbcross](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5642#issuecomment-162620127) in [issue #5642](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5642) that clarifies a LOT in this matter.

Quoting part of that comment

> Modularity was a goal of the new RxJS project from the start, and it wasn't until recently that we started really getting serious about composing operators instead of relying on tiered distributions of Rx.

**Original answer**

There was actually a breaking change regarding RxJS and Angular2. So now to use operators like `map` you have to import them separately. You can see the change in this [pull request](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS/pull/843). And there's already an [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5632) about your question.

I recommend you to stick to alpha 47. But to everyone who needs and want to know what the solution is, like in the pull request is specified, to add the operator separately.

You must have something like this

```js
import {Http, ...} ...;

// Component
constructor(http: Http) {
    http.get(...).map() // 'map' doesn't exist! Ouch!
}
```

To fix it, add the operator (sorry for repeating it so many times) and configure the paths to rxjs

**Note**

This must be done with RxJS alpha 11, or alpha 12 (*don't confuse it with `@reactivex/rxjs`, now it's just `rxjs`*). So install it with

```js
npm install rxjs@5.0.0-alpha.11
```

Or just `npm install rxjs` if you want the latest, although they [lock it](https://github.com/robwormald/angular/commit/da0f27fc65b8943930742724de28e399a715b413) to be alpha 11.

Configure the paths in your System.config (note that this is my config, not necessarily the best and I'm assuming you installed alpha 11)

```js
System.config({
    paths: {
        'rxjs/observable/*' : 'node_modules/rxjs/observable/*.js',
        'rxjs/operators/*' : 'node_modules/rxjs/operators/*.js',
        'rxjs/*' : 'node_modules/rxjs/*.js'
    }
});
```

After you are done with the configuration, you can import the operator as follows

```js
 import 'rxjs/operators/map';
```

And that's all. You'll have to do that with every operator. So I repeat, I recommend you to stick to alpha 47, like I told you in the comment. I will try to update the answer later with a plnkr.

Comment: Thanks a million Eric! I am going downgrade to 47 and keep an eye on those threads. ;0)

Comment: I guess that the conclusion for now is that we will have to import the operators from the RxJS. We won't have a convenient way of importing them from the Angular 2 library. Thanks for the updates Eric! ;0)

Comment: You're welcome. I personally like this, I think it's just a matter of getting used to it.

Comment: I think this is version rxjs@5.0.0-beta.2 now

Comment: @EricMartinez Although it works when you run it, Visual Studio still cannot recognize the map function. Is there a way for VS to recognize it? Thanks.

Comment: I'm getting this error now and I'm confused with the answer. Which of the updates are still relevant to the latest version? Is it only "another update", or the other updates below it too? Doing the import statement alone without any additional System.config doesn't work for me.

Comment: @EricMartinez thanks for this great answer. Can you update this answer for Angular CLI that now uses the WebPack. I'm getting map not found.

Answer (score 14):

If you want to use the Beta versions of Angular 2 or the future real production releases, then you need to do two things to get this to work.

1) You'll first need to update your System.config() configuration in index.html to include references to RxJS:

```
System.config({
    map: {
        'rxjs': 'node_modules/rxjs'
    },
    packages: {
        'app': {defaultExtension: 'js'}, // assumes your code sites in `src/app`
        'rxjs': {defaultExtension: 'js'}
    }
});
System.import('app/app'); // this assumes your main file is `app.ts` and it sits in the `app` folder.
```

2) Then you can import `map()` and other (or all) RxJS operators into your application with `import` lines in your main file (app.ts in my case):

```
import 'rxjs/Rx'; // this would import all RxJS operators
```

If you rather import just `map()` to keep the size down, you would do this instead:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

You **do not** need to import these into each class file.  Just import them into your main file to make them accessible to all your other components/services/directives.

Comment: To those coming here, this is the working current solution, although the accepted answer might be useful for previous versions.

Answer (score 5):

You need to import the Rx map operator in your component like

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

Cheers!

Comment: What's the point of adding this answer to already correctly answered and accepted questions?

Comment: I thought it's short enough than a big paragraph

Comment: Best answer here by a long shot! Brevity counts!

Answer (score 0):

In contrast to what what's written above, I found that I needed to use

```
    System.config({
        packages: {
            'app': {defaultExtension: 'js'},
            'node_modules': {defaultExtension: 'js'}
        },
        paths: {
            'rxjs/*' : 'node_modules/rxjs/*.js'
        }
    });
```

The `node_modules` `defaultExtension` was the critical think for me (I dunno why the `rxjs/*` path doesn't add the `.js` but hey ho.)

This works from 48 to the latest 52.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and it turned out to be an issue with the version of rxjs - angular 2.0.0-rc4 requires rxjs-5.0.0-beta.6, I had beta.10 in my jspm config!