# Angular2 alpha.48 can't import rxjs/operators

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have tried the solutions that was proposed on github [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5661) to do an import of the said operator like so:

```
import 'rxjs/operators/debounceTime';
```

But I keep getting erros that say : rxjs/operators/debounceTime 404 (Not Found)

I have installed rxjs from npm (local project) also as recommended and typescript doesn't show any errors. How can I get this to work?

Plunker example [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ph4cBY7DxAYyBeStsrHI?p=preview)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/34113985/4933038

Comment: I have followed the link you posted and got debounceTime and switchMap imported thanks for that. But it seems that their dependencies are not imported. The console now spits out 404s of all the dependents of debounceTime and switchMap. I used the same paths as you posted and also included all the rest. Any idea how to fix this? Or rather do you know how to import and use debounceTime with all its dependents?

Comment: What are you getting exactly? What are those dependencies? A few examples would be nice. I can't reproduce it in a plnkr (can't get a cdn for each operator, etc) nor my local env.

Comment: Here is a working alpha.48 sample with http ++ https://github.com/thelgevold/angular-2-samples

Comment: I found the problem. It was in the System.config object. It was configured with packages: {'app': {defaultExtension: 'js'}}. I have removed that line and replaced it with defaultJSExtensions: true and the app spat back to life. Not sure what the difference is. Thanks for the help :)