# Angular2 RxJS getting 'Observable_1.Observable.fromEvent is not a function' error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, reactive-extensions-js

I'm using AngularJS 2 Beta 0 and I'm trying to create an RxJS Observable from an event on a window object.  I believe I know the formula for capturing the event as an Observable in my service:

```
var observ = Observable.fromEvent(this.windowHandle, 'hashchange');
```

The problem is that every time I try run this code, I get an error stating that 'fromEvent' is not a function.

```
Uncaught EXCEPTION: Error during evaluation of "click"
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Observable_1.Observable.fromEvent is not a function
```

This seems to imply to me that I'm not handling my `import` correctly now that RxJS is not included in the build of Angular 2, though the rest of my application functions properly, which to me means that RxJS is where it is supposed to be.

My import in the service looks like this:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

Though I have also tried to use this instead (with the appropriate changes to the code), with the same results:

```
import {FromEventObservable} from 'rxjs/observable/fromEvent';
```

I have the following configuration in my Index.html:

```
<script>
    System.config({
        map: {
            rxjs: 'node_modules/rxjs'
        },
        packages: {
            'app': {defaultExtension: 'js'},
            'rxjs': {defaultExtension: 'js'}
        }
    });
    System.import('app/app');
</script>
```

Can somebody tell me what I'm doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Its definitly not needed to import all operators at once! You just imported `fromEvent` wrong.
You could do it like this:

```js
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromEvent';
```

EDIT: In addititon to what I already wrote: tree-shaking with the AoT-Compiler of angular removes unused code, based on what you import. If you just import some objects or functions from rxjs/rx, the compiler can't remove anything. Always import just, what you need!

Comment: Note that you have to capitalize the 'O' in rxjs/Observable. I looked for this error forever.

Comment: This is the better answer. Importing all of rxjs will definitely slow your startup time.

Comment: This is definitely the better solution even if @Michael_Oryl's solves it.

Comment: Note: ng serve with --aot might not pick up the new import and keep complaining until you kill it and start it again.

Answer (score 74):

The problem seemed to be that the import statement should look like this:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
```

Note that `Observable` is being brought in from `rxjs/Rx` instead of from `rxjs/Observable`.  [As @EricMartinez mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34113750/http-post-not-exposing-the-map-function/34113985#34113985), pulling it in this way will automagically get you all of the operators (like `.map()`).

Comment: why do we add everything from rxjs, couldn't we add only the needed parts

Comment: @MahmoudHboubati yes you can bring in just the needed parts. See the answer below.. which is the proper way to import things so that you don't bloat your asset bundle.

Comment: This is not recommended usage.. you should NEVER import ALL operators (thus never use from 'rxjs/RX'

Comment: Importing all operators have just overloaded the app, Its recommended to include only required operators.