# Creating an Observable for Mock Data in Angular 2

Tags: promise, angular, observer-pattern

I am trying to return an Observable from a service with mock data.

I am returning this from my service :

```
return Observable.of(new Object()).map(MOCKACCOUNT =>JSON.stringify(MOCKACCOUNT));
```

I get an error

> Observable_1.Observable.of is not a function.

Am I missing some include?  I am importing

```
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
```

Note:  I was returning a mock promise prior but based on my understanding I would not be able to interpolate the value.  For example `{{returnFromServiceStoredInExportedClass.name}}`

Comment: I have a sample where I mock an Observable here: http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/angular-2.0-unit-testing

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Looks like

```
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
```

should be

```
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Rx";
```

See also [Angular2 RxJS getting 'Observable_1.Observable.fromEvent is not a function' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34397162/angular2-rxjs-getting-observable-1-observable-fromevent-is-not-a-function-erro)

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: Interesting. What's the difference between the `Observable` from `rxjs/Observable` and the `Observable` from `rxjs/Rx`?

Comment: `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'` will work only as the interface. `import {Observable} from "rxjs/Rx"` is the function itself along with all of the operators.

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
return Observable.of(new Object()).mapTo(MOCKDATA);`
```

The import statement is fine.

```
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
```

Also need to import the ts file for MOCKDATA

```
import {MOCKDATA} from "../path_to_mockdata";
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
```

because

```
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Rx";
```

will import all other operators that you don't need