# Observable from <button> click event in Angular2

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-observables

What's the preferred way to create an observable from a button's onclick event using Angular 2?

I'm not sure if it's considered best practice to grab the native element from the DOM in the component code (how do I do this?), or if there's some other shortcut I don't know about.

Comment: See https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4062

Comment: @MarkRajcok, thanks that's enlightening. What's a good way to do this today?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use `Observable.fromEvent` like explained in [Angular2 RxJS getting 'Observable_1.Observable.fromEvent is not a function' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34397162/angular2-rxjs-getting-observable-1-observable-fromevent-is-not-a-function-erro)

Or just forward to an observable like

```ts
private obs = new Subject();
public obs$ = this.obs.asObservable();

@HostListener('click', ['$event']) 
clickHandler(event){
  this.obs.next(event);
}
```

or

```ts
<button (click)="obs.next($event)">
```

Comment: I don't agree with the second approach after reading the creator of rxjs article.
https://medium.com/@benlesh/on-the-subject-of-subjects-in-rxjs-2b08b7198b93

Answer (score 49):

Don't overthink it.

```
@ViewChild('button') button;
clicks$:Observable<any>;

ngOnInit() {
  this.clicks$ = Observable.fromEvent(this.button.nativeElement, 'click');
}
```

Comment: Note: if the button is initially hidden due to an *ngIf then button will be null. While there are ways to work around this (by using a setter for `button` and flatmap / switchmap) it can quickly get complicated. In these cases it's better to use Jon's answer.

Comment: I think the fromEvent should be called in an ngAfterViewInit callback because in the ngOnInit this.button is still undefined...

Comment: from RxJS 6 `Observable.fromEvent()` is been deprecated. Use only `fromEvent()` instead of `Observable.fromEvent()`.

Comment: Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'nativeElement')

Answer (score 16):

@Gunter's example didn't quite work for me, because my compiler didn't recognize `publ`.

Here's an example of what worked for me:
`modal.component.ts`

```
import { Output, Component } from '@angular/core';
import {Subject} from "rxjs/Subject";

export class MyModal{

    private clickStream = new Subject<Event>();

    @Output() observ = this.clickStream.asObservable();

    buttonClick(event:Event){
        this.clickStream.next(event);
    }
}
```

Inside `modal.component.html`:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="buttonClick($event)">click me</button>
```

Answer (score 6):

If you try to use @ViewChild and your button isn't visible on the page at init time (due to an *ngIf) then the assignment will be null.

You can use a setter in conjunction with @ViewChild, and run your initialization when the button first appears.

```
@ViewChild('btnAdd')
set btnAdd(btnAdd: Button) { ... }
```

This quickly gets clumsy and inconvenient - especially if you create an observable stream from this.

A hybrid way might be as follows:

```
btnAskAnotherClicks$ = new Subject<Event>();

<button mat-flat-button (click)="btnAskAnotherClicks$.next($event)">Ask another question...</button>
```

This allows you to use the click stream  to create chains, but no issues if the button is initially hidden due to *ngIf.

Don't like `next` in your template? Neither do I particularly. But I'm ok with `async`, and they're both implementation details. Well that's up to you to decide -)

Comment: It also turns out you can also do `new Subject<void>()` and then `btn.next()` without needing to pass a value. This can be useful if there's no useful meaning of the event.

Comment: Currently using exhaustMap inside the pipe of the subject to stop spamming http calls. But after one call is finished the "spammer" can keep going. Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

For those using AngularMaterial buttons and pipeable RxJS operators, some slight mods to @JoshuaDavid's answer:

Some button in template tagged with a template variable:

```
<button #btnTemplateName mat-icon-button></button>
```

The component code:

```
import { Observable, fromEvent } from 'rxjs';

// Note importing from lettable/pipeable operators - 'operators' plural
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { MatButton } from '@angular/material/button';

//Access the button through the template variable, typed to MatButton
@ViewChild('btnTemplateName') myBtn: MatButton;
myBtnClicks$: Observable<any>;


ngAfterViewInit() {

    // Note the need to access the native element in MatButton through the extended property chain
    this.myBtnClicks$ = 
      Observable.fromEvent(this.myBtn._elementRef.nativeElement, 'click');

    // Can now subscribe (using lettable/pipeable operators)
    this.myBtnClicks$.pipe(
       tap(() => console.log("Button clicked")),
    )
    .subscribe(event => console.log("Event:" + JSON.stringify(event)));
}
```