# Observable.fromEvent is not a function - RxJS

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I would like to use RxJS without Angular or Webpack. I just included RxJS 7 from a CDN. This is what I tried:

```js
const { Observable } = rxjs;

const clicks = Observable.fromEvent(document, 'click');

clicks.subscribe(ev => console.log(ev))
```

I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Observable.fromEvent is not a function
```

My html code looks like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.3.0/rxjs.umd.js" integrity="sha512-1Jz97rlEAHdMk6x3UWesQaEOhSZ3iG82PkqNr3N4bj/hqKaVQDPTeHW0//vU1ucY+pB5sZr5uNz1aO2qO5XkMg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script src="demo.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    demo
</body>
</html>
```

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34397162/angular2-rxjs-getting-observable-1-observable-fromevent-is-not-a-function-erro), but that is different, because it uses Angular, but I don't use any build system, just include it from a CDN.

What do I wrong? How to use `Observable.fromEvent`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting from `RxJS@6`, `fromEvent` function is not a part of the `Observable` class, and instead, you need to use it directly from `rxjs`.

Try the following:

```js
const { Observable, fromEvent } = rxjs;

const clicks = fromEvent(document, 'click');

clicks.subscribe(ev => console.log(ev));
```

Answer (score 1):

Import `fromEvent` and use that directly instead of importing `Observable`.

`import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs';`

Edit: my apologies as I forgot you are in the browser side. Using the CDN will declare the global variable `rxjs` so you should use `rxjs.fromEvent`.

Comment: I use it in plain html+js. There is no import statement: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

Answer (score -1):

Use rxjs version 5.x or update your imports