# Add rxjs to Angular2 Quick Start and System.js packages?

Tags: angular, rxjs, systemjs

I'm trying to extend the angular2 quick start framework (https://angular.io/guide/quickstart) to include rxjs, and to also have System.js load the rxjs code from the bundle instead of loading 100's of individual .js files.

System.js config.map:

```
{
  "@app": "app/@app",
  "@angular": "node_modules/@angular",
  "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api",
  "rxjs": "node_modules/rxjs"
}
```

System.js config.packages:

```
{
  "@app": {
    "defaultExtension": "js"
  },
  "rxjs": {
    "main": "/bundles/Rx.umd.js",
    "defaultExtension": "js"
  },
  "angular2-in-memory-web-api": {
    "main": "index.js",
    "defaultExtension": "js"
  },
  "@angular/common": {
    "main": "/bundles/common.umd.min.js",
    "defaultExtension": "js"
  },
  "@angular/compiler": {
    "main": "/bundles/compiler.umd.min.js",
    "defaultExtension": "js"
  },
  "@angular/core": {
    "main": "/bundles/core.umd.min.js",
    "defaultExtension": "js"
  },
  "@angular/forms": {
    "main": "/bundles/forms.umd.min.js",
    "defaultExtension": "js"
  },
  "@angular/http": {
    "main": "/bundles/http.umd.min.js",
    "defaultExtension": "js"
  },
  "@angular/platform-browser": {
    "main": "/bundles/platform-browser.umd.min.js",
    "defaultExtension": "js"
  },
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": {
    "main": "/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.min.js",
    "defaultExtension": "js"
  },
  "@angular/router": {
    "main": "/bundles/router.umd.min.js",
    "defaultExtension": "js"
  },
  "@angular/router-deprecated": {
    "main": "/bundles/router-deprecated.umd.min.js",
    "defaultExtension": "js"
  },
  "@angular/upgrade": {
    "main": "/bundles/upgrade.umd.min.js",
    "defaultExtension": "js"
  }
}
```

Sample import statements form .ts files:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {AsyncSubject} from 'rxjs/AsyncSubject';
```

I can't see why this is still loading all individual rxjs files instead of recognizing the package and loading it instead. It loads all @angular/* packages as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 var packages = {
    'rxjs':{ defaultExtension: 'js' }
  };
```

There is no main file mentioned in the [tutorial](https://angular.io/guide/quickstart)

[Try this answer also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34113750/angular-2s-http-service-not-exposing-map-and-other-rxjs-functions/34113985#34113985)

Comment: The quickstart does make use of the 'main' setting thru the packUmd() function, which sets the value for each of the various packages within @angular (@angular/common, @angular/compiler, etc). I am just following the same format for rxjs and adding what I think should be the correct values.

Comment: I use webpack so I'm not so big help. Update me if you find out what was the issue. You can take a look at my seed I'd you want [here is seed](https://github.com/jorawarsingh/angular2-webpack-seed)