# How to use RxJS in an angular2-meteor project?

Tags: meteor, angular, angular-meteor, angular2-meteor

I have an angular2-meteor project.

I tried to use RxJS, so I added these in my code:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
```

But when I run it, it shows:

> Cannot find module 'rxjs/Observable'.

Do I need install any package from [Atmosphere](https://atmospherejs.com/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should this import:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'; // for example to add a specific operator
```

instead of this one:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

I don't Atmosphere but this package is what you define in the `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "apispark-angular2",
  (...)
  "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.0",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.0",  <---------------
    "systemjs": "0.19.6",
    "zone.js": "0.5.10"
  },
  (...)
}
```

You need it to make work Angular2. For example class `EventEmitter` class extends the `Subject` class that is part of the rxjs library...

Comment: Thanks, but angular2-meteor is little different. I updated in my question. I still haven't found way to make Rx run.

Comment: What did you include into your HTML page regarding RxJS? `node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js`? Because in this file, you can see at the end that the `rxjs/Rx` module is registered: `System.register("rxjs/Rx", ["rxjs/Subject", "rxjs/Observable", ...`. The version I use is the `5.0.0-beta.0` one. Do you have the same?

Comment: I am not 100% sure. In the angular2-meteor project we don't add in HTML directly. However, inside the file **"typings/main.d.ts"** I added in tsconfig.json, it is `/// <reference path="main/ambient/rx/rx.d.ts" />`, and the **rx.d.ts** content is same like [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/4d86cc24082d6703ecaee46ecc970bd0ac744236/rx/rx.d.ts)

Comment: You can see [here](http://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular2/bootstrapping), after step 0.6

Comment: Okay I see. What do you have in the `index.html` page you get in the browser regarding `<script>` includes?

Comment: I don't have `index.html` and `package.json`, I only have `tsconfig.json`. But I tried to add `index.html`, but still no idea what should be inside of `<script>` after checking [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33379851/how-to-load-rxjs-in-a-minimal-angular-2-app-using-systemjs. I will probably stay with EventEmitter first as temporary way... It is too hard to set up Rx with angular2-meteor which already took me two days..

Comment: wow, it is weird, I tried again today using `import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';`
`import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';`, it is working!! thanks!!